# update_term_meta not working

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I am trying to remove a string off of a bunch of slugs in terms from a CPT taxonomy.

For example, I have a term named "Accounting" but the slug has the "accounting-expert-witnesses" I just need to remove the "-expert-witnesses" part of the slug.

I am using this post as a reference as it appears to be what am I looking for but I cannot seem to get any of the suggestions to work: [How to update taxonomy custom field with wp_update_term()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58938/how-to-update-taxonomy-custom-field-with-wp-update-term)

I have tried using update_term_meta, update_post_meta, wp_update_term and none of them are doing what I need.

The closest I've got is using update_term_meta and it appears to be working when I error log the result however when I look at the terms in the dashboard nothing has been updated.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    function remove_stuff() {
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'experts_industries',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    foreach($terms as $term) {

        $newSlug = str_replace('-expert-witnesses', '' , $term->slug);

        //update_term_meta($term->id, 'slug', $newSlug);

        //update_post_meta($term->id, 'slug', $newSlug); 

        wp_update_term($term->id, 'experts_industries', array( 'slug' => $newSlug ));

        error_log($term->slug);

    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'remove_stuff' );
```

Comment: are you trying to partially update the value? Or are you setting an entire new value? Where is the code that displays your meta in the dashboard? Are you updating or are you adding meta?

Comment: I updated my question to try and better articulate what I'm trying to do and what I've tried. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: If you're trying to change the slug of a term across the board, `wp_update_term` would the right function to use. A slug isn't meta, and a term isn't a post, so those 2 functions are not appropriate. Are you certain `wp_update_term` did not work? Are you sure you're not still looking at cached data?

Comment: Yeah I've refreshed the page and ran the code no less than a dozen times. Nothing is getting updated.  Is there something wrong in here: wp_update_term($term->id, 'experts_industries', array( 'slug' => $newSlug )); this is starting to drive me nuts.

Comment: vancoder is right, term slugs are _not_ stored as term meta, you should not be using `update_term_meta` to change a terms slug, and `update_post_meta` has nothing to do with term slugs. Also outputting `$term->slug` is not a way to test if your code updated the database, `$term->slug` is just outputting what you already have, it's not grabbing the value fresh from the database everytime you use it

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that out. However, it doesn't work. update_term_meta is not doing anything and I cannot figure out why. Even if I manually define each parameter of the update_term_meta function and then call it, nothing changes. The following code does not update the slug of the term with the ID of 0: wp_update_term(0, 'experts_industries', array( 'slug' => 'does-this-even-work' ));

Comment: there should be no terms with an ID of 0

Comment: whoops its actually this: wp_update_term(5046, 'experts_industries', array( 'slug' => 'does-this-even-work' )); - and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Possibly a stupid question but you're sure `experts_industries` is the correct taxonomy name? It shouldn't be hyphenated?

Comment: yeah that's correct. I even changed the code to pull the term id and the taxonomy name from the term it self wp_update_term( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy, array('slug' => $newSlug) ); this is nuts, i can't see any reason why this isn't working

Comment: As Tom indicates, you should place the result of your update in a var, so you can check for an error: `$update = wp_update_term...` then `if ( is_wp_error( $update )) { wp_die( $update->get_error_message()) }`.

Comment: I also wonder how you are confirming this hasn't worked. Are you checking the DB? WP admin?

Comment: Yeah, I error logged the return, it's telling me the taxonomy is invalid... not sure how that can be as the exact same taxonomy name is working just fine in the get_terms function...

Comment: @grzybowski1911 it may be helpful to include your code that registers the `experts_industries` taxonomy in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A terms slug is not stored as meta/custom fields, and it's definitely not post meta, so `update_term_meta` and `update_post_meta` are innapropriate and can never be used to achieve your goal.

The correct function is `wp_update_term`, however you've used that incorrectly too:

- `$term->id` isn't a thing, if we look at the `WP_Term` class and the examples on the official docs, we see `$term->term_id` is what should be used
- there is no code checking the return value of `wp_update_term`, if it failed there would have been a `WP_Error` object with an error message explaining what happened.
- `error_log($term->slug);` doesn't fetch the new slug from the database or make a new query to check for a new slug, this cannot be used to test if it worked. You need to check the return value of `wp_update_term` instead

From the official dev docs:

> ### Return
>
> (array|WP_Error) An array containing the term_id and term_taxonomy_id, WP_Error otherwise.

More examples and information at:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/

Comment: Thanks. By all accounts, this should work. However it does not work with any of the custom post-type taxonomies, it always returns "invalid taxonomy" works great with default categories taxonomy on the posts content type though. Idk. I'm giving up, going to just update all the slugs manually I guess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you're running the code before the taxonomies are registered or on a request were the taxonomies are not registered then it will fail. Likewise if the capitalisation is different. Taxonomies and post types should be registered on the `init` hook. Also if you've not changed `id` to `term_id` then your taxonomy will never match the term as the term will always be `null` or `0`

Comment: It was because of the action hook priority. The person who set up the action hook to create cpt taxonomies had set the priority way low and my code was executing before the cpt code was resulting in the invalid taxonomy error. The code in your answer remains correct. Thanks again I appreciate the help.